# How do I install a fingerprint reader on Lenovo ThinkPad?

Tags: software-installation, lenovo, thinkpad, fingerprint-reader

I have a [Lenovo ThinkPad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ThinkPad) with a fingerprint reader:

[image: Thinkpad fingerprint]

How to make Ubuntu recognise it and use it for login?

I already tried:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fingerprint/fingerprint-gui
sudo apt-get update
```

... but this GUI did not recognizes my device. Does anyone knows any other option?

Comment: Do you know the fingerprint device's model/manufacturer/id? It may appear in `lspci -v` or `lsusb -v`.

Comment: According to the [Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fingerprint-gui), you might need to reboot or add yourself to the `plugdev` and `scanner` groups (you should alread be in the `plugdev` group).

Comment: how I add my user on the 'plugdev'???

Comment: Read `man useradd` and do something like `sudo useradd --groups=plugdev,scanner $USER`. Then logout - groups are only applied at login time. Well, not exactly, but logout/login is the easiest way.

Comment: Can you see the fingerprint reader in the output of `sudo lspci -v` or `sudo lsusb -v`? If so, please edit your question to share the information.

Comment: My new L380 fingerprint sensor is not recognized. any driver? With `lsusb` All my Lenovo devices begin with `17ef:`

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I tried both Fingerprint Gui and FPrint in my Thinkpad W550S. [Fingerprint Gui (Dead link, project is gone???)](http://zecheru.com/thinkpad-fingerprint-ubuntu-14-04/?v=7516fd43adaa) had a nice interface, but was pretty unstable on the login page and sudo and constantly crashed.

[FPrint](https://launchpad.net/%7Efingerprint/+archive/ubuntu/fprint) seems more simple, but works very well:

##### Installation

- For Ubuntu 20.04 or greater:

  ```
  sudo apt install libpam-fprintd
  ```
- For Ubuntu 16.04 or greater:

  ```
  sudo apt install libpam-fprintd fprint-demo
  ```
- For Ubuntu 15.04 or less

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:fingerprint/fprint
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install libfprint0 fprint-demo libpam-fprintd gksu-polkit
  ```

---

##### Configuration

After that, you can test it by running `fprint_demo` and save the fingerprint with `fprintd-enroll`. This will automatically make your login screen require a finger swipe instead of a password.

In some cases you also may need to run:

```
sudo pam-auth-update
```

... to activate fingerprint reader for elevated privileges, for example with `sudo`.

Comment: gksu-polkit does not exist in 2015.10 but seems to be installable: http://askubuntu.com/questions/653459/cant-install-gksu-says-it-cant-find-it

Comment: Actually no need to install gksu-polkit it seems.

Comment: the question was for 14.04. I didn't tested it in latest versions. But thank you anyway.

Comment: For 16.04, `apt-get install libpam-fprintd` was sufficient to get `fprintd-enroll` and functioning login page.

Comment: after setting this how to get back to entering the password

Comment: @Kostanos How to uninstall `Fprint` I installed it using `sudo apt install libpam-fprintd`

Comment: on firing `fprintd-enroll`, it asks `Enrolling right-index-finger finger`. On scrolling my finger on the fingerprint-scanner, the terminal shows `Enroll result: enroll-completed`. But when I try using my fingerprint, it always shows 'Failed to match fingerprint'. 
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: @v1h5 occasionally my sensor also gives me no match. but after few retries it works almost all the time. I guess it is also may depends on quality of the sensor and cleanest of it, also the fingers should not be wet.

Comment: @KasunSiyambalapitiya it exactly what I expressed on this topic. Apart of `libpam-fprintd` you may need some other dependent libraries. Check above for the full instruction.

Comment: Worked as a charm w/ ThinkPad L450 & Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: For 18.04 at least, it seems the answer is missing an important part -- the fingerprint registration needs to be run also as root and needs username of the normal user (to get access via the fingerprint) as parameter: `sudo fingerd-enroll $USERNAME`.

Comment: OK, so this does get the fingerprint thingy working but.. it's pretty useless on Ubuntu if you still have to enter a password for the key chain after paswordless fingerprint login :(

Comment: I am getting no devices available. in ThinkPad l480

Comment: unfortunately some models. including mine - ideapad 720s, has different brand fingerprint reader, which is not supported by ubuntu yet :(

Comment: fprint_demo says no devices found in status

Comment: no device found

Comment: No device found, too.

Comment: http://zecheru.com/thinkpad-fingerprint-ubuntu-14-04/?v=7516fd43adaa is a dead link

Comment: NB! On KUbuntu (Ubuntu with KDE) this approach prevented logging in after running `fprintd-enroll` even with password! Login screen staid "frozen" until reboot. Fingerprint worked on command line, but not on login-screen! 
Rescue solution: 
1) In login screen switch from GUI to terminal single-user mode (using Ctrl + Alt + F3)
2) log in with your user (there in terminal fingerprint actually worked) - after login you still can use only terminal, but not GUI!
3) edit `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` by removing line containing `pam_fprintd.so`
4) log out - now logging in with password works again

Comment: FYI: Related to KUbuntu login issue i mentioned above, i also reported bug: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/libfprint/-/issues/515

Comment: On Ubuntu 23.10, running `fprint_demo` gives this error: `fprint_demo: command not found`

Answer (score 6):

[Fprint](https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/ubuntu/fprint) worked perfectly on a Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon under Ubuntu 14.04.
I strictly followed the instructions :

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:fingerprint/fprint
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libfprint0 fprint-demo libpam-fprintd
```

and finally saved my fingerprint  with `fprintd-enroll`.
I can now login and validate my `sudo` access with a finger swipe !!

Comment: Oh wow, had my T440s for 3 years and just now realized that fprint works wonderfully. That's pretty sweet!

Comment: what is the difference in your answer from the previous one?

Comment: @AlbinFreycenon will this works on `x1 carbon 5th gen`?

Comment: no device found in ubuntu 16

Comment: `list_devices failed: No devices available ` on Thinkpad P43s , Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 2):

On my Thinkpad X220, I had to enable the fingerprint reader in BIOS (tap F1 repeatedly after starting the computer).

After that, fprint_demo works in the sense that it runs, but it fails to read any fingerprint data ("Bad scan. Please remove your finger before trying again.").

Comment: I just want to use like i was using it on windows.

Answer (score 1):

It works on Thinkpad **x270** and perhaps others **70 models with [python-validity](https://github.com/uunicorn/python-validity) the installation is described on the project repository.
Note this is an experimental package.

Answer (score 0):

I have a T590 and fingerprint is now working in Ubuntu 20.10!

I installed the update in the "Software" app.

Comment: You can try this module. It works for my T470: https://github.com/uunicorn/python-validity

Answer (score 0):

Just want to say that this is working on my Thinkpad T14 Gen 2 (a used laptop I got off eBay). These are the instructions I did to make it work

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fingerprint/fprint
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get install libfprint0 fprint-demo libpam-fprintd

fprintd-enroll
```

I believe the demo and libpam failed, but I was still able to do `fprintd-entroll` and log into my computer with my fingerprint. Very cool!

Comment: Doesn't work for 22.04 as ppa isn't suitable