# Can't install gksu. Says it can't find it

Tags: command-line, downloads, gksu

Can't install gksu every time I put in the command to install I get the same thing
unable to locate package gksu
any ideas

Comment: which release are you on ? also do you have `universe` repo enabled ?

Comment: gksu is depreciated See http://askubuntu.com/questions/284306/why-is-gksu-no-longer-installed-by-default . It is in universe http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gksu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you go to the [developer site](http://www.nongnu.org/gksu/) it states: gksu is being replaced by PolicyKit, please take a look at http://live.gnome.org/gksu (link dead; see https://wiki.gnome.org/Attic/gksu ). It says there ...

> **gksu**
>
> gksu is a library and application used to ask the user for passwords
>   to run programs as root. It is not a good option now that we have
>   PolicyKit. Still, we still have applications which are not written to
>   take advantage of the PolicyKit framework, and since making
>   applications use it usually involves structural changes, a new version
>   of gksu will provide functionality similar to the one provided by the
>   current gksu to cover applications which still haven't been patched to
>   use PolicyKit. The new gksu will use PolicyKit as backend, instead of
>   su and sudo. This page intends to work as a notebook for
>   planning/designing that new version.
>
> **Show me the code**
>
> Code is being written, and you can fetch it by using git:
>
> ```
> $ git clone git://git.debian.org/~kov/gksu-polkit.git/
> ```
>
> **General Architecture**
>
> The new gksu will be composed of three parts:
>
> - an activable dbus system service able to run programs as root or other users, using PolicyKit to enforce policy
> - a library providing a simple API that talks to this service an application that is client of the above library, and allows people to
> - run programs in a way similar to the one they are able to do with current gksu

So if you want the newest version use the above.

Otherwise check Ubuntu software center, open up Universe, update the sources and you can install it from either USC...

[image]

... or from command line with

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
```

Comment: gksu-polkit seems to be old & possibly abandoned?

Comment: I should stalk you some more: I always learn...  :P

Comment: Link to http://live.gnome.org/gksu is dead.

Comment: check. editted in the link shown on the 404 page

Answer (score 0):

Maybe **[pkexec](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pkexec)** is what you searching for:

```
pkexec --user root program
```