# Booting into Linux via ThinkPad Fingerprint reader

Tags: login, thinkpad, fingerprint-reader

I use a ThinkPad T420 with Ubuntu 14.04 and wanted to ask if there is a program to use so that when the computer is off or in sleep I can swipe my finger and have it turn on and log in automatically. I tried fingerprint GUI but it doesn't do that. I know that there are divers to make it does this in Windows but im still new to Linux and don't know how to do this. 
Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am on the same situation, I have a Lenovo ThinkPad T420 running Ubuntu 14.04 and followed this tutorial (http://askubuntu.com/questions/511876/how-to-install-a-fingerprint-reader-on-lenovo-thinkpad-with-ubuntu-14-04) and it worked! I don't know why you have to run `fprint_demo`, because I enrolled more than one finger there, as in Windows (I dual boot) and on the command `fprintd-enroll` it just lets you enroll the index finger (I enrolled my middle one because it's way easier for me, but shhhh!). Hope you can deal with your problem! I don't know much about coding yet, but if you need anythi