# Fingerprint and NFC reader on Dell Latitude E7450

Tags: drivers, fingerprint-reader, 15.10, nfc

Is there any solution to get the fingerprint reader and  the NFC reader to work on a Dell Latitude E7450? I have been looking for a way to get them working since the E7450 2015 was released.

Fingerprint GUI 1.06 reports `No Device Found`.

lsusb reports:

```
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0a5c:5804 Broadcom Corp. BCM5880 Secure Applications Processor with fingerprint swipe sensor
```

Haven't even found many questions asked about getting this to work. Either the model E7450 (2015) is not selling that well. Or the user bought it are running Windows where Dell has drivers supplied.

Or people don't care about those two features at all, but I do.. =)

Comment: I have same problem. Model 7470, Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Did you try the fprintd package, then check the man page   man fprintd to run it.

Comment: I just did, doesn't seem to find the fingerprint reader E7470, Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 4):

If you check the fprint page for supported devices you will see that yours (0a5c:5804) is not included, so you cannot expect it to appear in the fprint-gui. It is just not supported.
Page is: https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/ubuntu/fprint

The fprint project is not moving anymore, since quite some time, so you should not expect any solution, if you do not start coding (or persuade someone to do it for you).

Sorry, but no luck.

**EDIT:**

- The exact page of the supported devices by fprint is: https://fprint.freedesktop.org/supported-devices.html
- After 2 years, the Broadcom chips are still not supported.
- I hope someone (Joe? ) might have done some progress with that, but it is not visible in fprint's pages.
- The rest of the proposed solutions (gui) are based on the fprint. 
  So, the outcome remains: Sorry, no luck.

Answer (score 1):

This is just wrong. We should point people at resources not tell them that they're shit out of luck. I also have the same fingerprint reader (though in a Dell e7240) as does another individual who just posted to the fingerprint-gui forum 2 weeks (also with a e7240 but, again, we all share the same fingerprint reader).

This sucks. I've never done any software development for an OS or driver development but I'll look into it and see what I can find out.

Answer (score 0):

The fingerprint readers usualy show up as a serial device in /dev/ they arent complex devices you could probably write something to interpret the stream in python, but why bother, someone else has saved you the trouble!

Try using this repo, to install fingerprint-gui

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:fingerprint/fingerprint-gui && sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install libbsapi policykit-1-fingerprint-gui fingerprint-gui
```

fingerprint-gui may have some gnome / gtk specific dependencies, but i dont see a Desktop environment specified. I'm also sure other options exist in KDE.

[oh dang, another thread just like this one.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/511876/how-to-install-a-fingerprint-reader-on-lenovo-thinkpad)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a package called `thinkfinger` was used around the time of Ubuntu 10.04. But trying to install the package now gives issues errors which are mainly caused because the package uses deprecated gcc methods and arguments.

For more information, visit https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ThinkFinger

For now `gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '--strip-all'; did you mean '--warn-all'?` is the only error that I am getting. I was able to resolve rest of the problems(such as PAM Header files not found, etc) one way or the other.

In case anyone knows more about this package or anything similar please write in comments so that we can solve this problem together