# ubuntu 16.04 wakes up immediately from suspend after installing Fprint in lenovo T530

Tags: 16.04, suspend, power-management, lenovo, wakeup

I have read the posts on stackoverflow [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148481/how-do-i-prevent-immediate-wake-up-from-suspend-and-or-hibernation) and [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598236/ubuntu-wakes-up-after-few-seconds-of-sleep) but I cannot find which to disable, I'm having  `Ubuntu 16.04` on lenovo T530 with `nVidia` graphics. I installed the finger print functionality following the answer posted by `Kostanos` in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/511876/how-to-install-a-fingerprint-reader-on-lenovo-thinkpad).
After installing it the finger print got working fine, but the laptop got started to  wakeup immediately from suspend. Here is the output of `cat /proc/acpi/wakeup`

```
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
LID   S4    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0D:00
SLPB      S3    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0E:00
IGBE      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:19.0
EXP3      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.2
XHCI      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:14.0
EHC1      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.0
EHC2      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1a.0
HDEF      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1b.0
```

and I run a log to find out which cause the system to wakeup, here is part of what the log indicate

```
journalctl --follow


 නෙවැ 23 12:40:29 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 dbus[842]: [system] Successfully activated service 'net.reactivated.Fprint'
නෙවැ 23 12:40:29 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 systemd[1]: Started Fingerprint Authentication Daemon.
නෙවැ 23 12:40:29 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 fprintd[23149]: ** Message: user 'kasun' claiming the device: 0
නෙවැ 23 12:40:29 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 fprintd[23149]: ** Message: now monitoring fd 14
නෙවැ 23 12:40:29 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 fprintd[23149]: ** Message: device 0 claim status 0
නෙවැ 23 12:40:29 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 fprintd[23149]: ** Message: no longer monitoring fd 14
නෙවැ 23 12:40:29 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 fprintd[23149]: ** Message: released device 0
නෙවැ 23 12:40:29 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
නෙවැ 23 12:40:29 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
නෙවැ 23 12:40:29 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 systemd-sleep[23159]: Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (nil)  error: No such file or directory
නෙවැ 23 12:40:29 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 systemd-sleep[23161]: /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wpasupplicant failed with error code 255.
නෙවැ 23 12:40:29 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 systemd-sleep[23159]: Suspending system...
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: PM: Preparing system for sleep (mem)
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.002 seconds) done.
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: PM: Suspending system (mem)
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: e1000e: EEE TX LPI TIMER: 00000011
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: thinkpad_acpi: EC reports that Thermal Table has changed
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: resuming kernel object tree...
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: resuming client object trees...
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: resuming display...
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: resuming console...
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending console...
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending display...
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: evicting buffers...
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: waiting for kernel channels to go idle...
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending client object trees...
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending kernel object tree...
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: PM: suspend of devices complete after 1393.149 msecs
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: PM: late suspend of devices complete after 15.780 msecs
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: e1000e 0000:00:19.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: PM: noirq suspend of devices complete after 16.157 msecs
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: ACPI : EC: EC stopped
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: PM: Saving platform NVS memory
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: Broke affinity for irq 16
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: Broke affinity for irq 30
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: Broke affinity for irq 16
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: Broke affinity for irq 30
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: Broke affinity for irq 31
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: Broke affinity for irq 1
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: Broke affinity for irq 8
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: Broke affinity for irq 9
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: Broke affinity for irq 12
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: Broke affinity for irq 16
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: Broke affinity for irq 19
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: Broke affinity for irq 23
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: Broke affinity for irq 27
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: Broke affinity for irq 30
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: Broke affinity for irq 31
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: Broke affinity for irq 33
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: ACPI: Low-level resume complete
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: ACPI : EC: EC started
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: x86: Booting SMP configuration:
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x1
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel:  cache: parent cpu1 should not be sleeping
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: CPU1 is up
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x2
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel:  cache: parent cpu2 should not be sleeping
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: CPU2 is up
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x3
නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel:  cache: parent cpu3 should not be sleeping
```

it shows only `නෙවැ 23 12:40:34 kasun-ThinkPad-T530 kernel: ACPI : EC: EC started` Can anyone help me to find out which device made the system to wakeup. Thanks in advance

Comment: As provided in the answer [http://askubuntu.com/questions/598236/ubuntu-wakes-up-after-few-seconds-of-sleep] by disabling `IGBE` the system suspended properly