# fprint_demo and fprintd_enroll not found Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: lenovo, 17.10, thinkpad, fingerprint-reader

My computer is a **lenovo thinkpad T510** .I followed the instructions given in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/511876/how-to-install-a-fingerprint-reader-on-lenovo-thinkpad) but after installation,
For Ubuntu 16.04 or greater:

```
sudo apt install libpam-fprintd
```

I tried to run it, but:

```
$ fprint_demo
The program 'fprint_demo' is currently not installed.
You can install it by typing: sudo apt install fprint-demo
$ fprint_enroll
fprint_enroll: command not found
```

What am I missing to make my fingerprint work?

Comment: Did you install [`fprint-demo`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/fprint-demo)? The posts also indicate the second command is `fprintd-enroll`, not `fprint_enroll`.

Comment: I edited the original answer to include `fprint-demo` in the instructions for 16.04

Comment: Yes I did it is working perfectly