# How to enable Thinkpad L380 Yoga fingerprint reader on Ubuntu 16.04/18.04?

Tags: 18.04, thinkpad, fingerprint-reader

I have a Thinkpad L380 Yoga.

It works great and the only thing that is not working for me is the fingerprint reader. Any idea how to activate and use it?

I saw some related posts like [How do I install a fingerprint reader on Lenovo ThinkPad?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/511876/how-do-i-install-a-fingerprint-reader-on-lenovo-thinkpad)

At the moment offers no compatibility with L380 fingerprint reader.

Here's the hardware information (it seems `06cb:00a2` is the fingerprint reader) from my machine:

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 06cb:00a2 Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 056a:5157 Wacom Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b604 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:13.0 Non-VGA unclassified device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Integrated Sensor Hub (rev 21)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d4e (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (4) I219-V (rev 21)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM961/PM961
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `06cb:00a2` is the ID of L380 yoga's fingerprint reader.

Based on my search result,
it seems like the drive is not yet provided.

Following post from Lenovo, L570 has a driver for Ubuntu. And since 380 is a successor of 370/570, hopefully they support it later on.

For more info please refer to the links below.
[Lenovo forum post regarding L570 fingerprint](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Linux-Discussion/How-can-I-use-the-L570-fingerprint-reader-with-Ubuntu-linux/m-p/4111436#U4111436)
[“Fingerprint readers integration” team](https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint)

By the way, I'm on the same page with you.