# How to use fingerprint reader with Ubuntu 20.04 and sssd (active directory)

Tags: 20.04, login, thinkpad, fingerprint-reader, active-directory

I've been trying to get fingerprint login working for a new Lenovo ThinkPad P15v, and had seen the information [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1239788/25344) and other places suggesting that fingerprint login was available in default 20.04 in the "Users" control panel.

Although no-one has shown screenshots as I understand the fingerprint UI should be here:

[image: User account settings control panel with space for fingerprint UI]

However as you can see it is not.  My best guess was that its absence was related to being on an active directory login - since that has caused other strange "gotchas", for example around Unix vs Active directory group membership, however I could not find any reference anywhere, and our IT didn't think they had any policies to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

Grabbing the source for the control panel I found `panels/user-accounts/cc-fingerprint-manager.c` I found the following short-circuit:

```
  if (act_user_get_uid (priv->user) != getuid () ||
      !act_user_is_local_account (priv->user))
    {
      set_state (self, CC_FINGERPRINT_STATE_NONE);
      return;
    }
```

So the section doesn't appear because the user account is not of the "local type".  Its not a policy setting from Active Directory, its a policy setting built into the fingerprint UI itself.  I've not been able to find any reason in particular for this limitation, perhaps it just an incomplete implementation.

However I did manage to get fingerprint login and lockscreen working.  The limitation is only in that one place in the control panel.  So just use the command-line to enroll some fingers:

```
$ fprintd-enroll -f right-index-finger
$ fprintd-enroll -f left-index-finger
$ fprintd-enroll -f right-middle-finger
```

Logging in/out may be required (haven't validated this), but now on the login and lock screens, after choosing a user (or hitting a key to bring up the password entry) it shows `(or swipe finger)` just pop your finger on the reader and in you go (can take around a second's delay).

Its possible future changes to Ubuntu and/or Gnome might make an official policy selection that could require Active Directory (or other remote account type policy) to enable fingerprints, but for now it works.