# How to remove fprint ubuntu focal release message from Ubuntu Software

Tags: 20.04

I'm just a week old into the world of Ubuntu.
I tried to install a package for the fingerprint scanner and ran into trouble. I did remove almost all the packages that I installed for it
Now in Ubuntu Software under the updates section when I check for new updates I get the following message
**Unable to download updates:
E:The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/fingerprint/fprint/-ubuntu focal release' doesn't have a release file.**
I wish to know how can i remove this message permanently
[image]

Comment: What commands did you use to install fprint scanner?

Comment: @AjayC
I used the command described in the following link 
https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/ubuntu/fprint
The commands I used are 
1. Add this PPA to your sources:
      sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fingerprint/fprint
      sudo apt-get update
      sudo apt-get upgrade
2. Install the software:
     sudo apt-get install libfprint0 fprint-demo libpam-fprintd
I got this through the below thread
https://askubuntu.com/questions/511876/how-do-i-install-a-fingerprint-reader-on-lenovo-thinkpad

I have removed all those installed via the terminal

Comment: You may want to remove the PPA as well. Graphically you can just open Software & Updates > Other software, select it and remove.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways you can remove fprint repository to remove the message.

1. As suggested by @chaganauto in the comments section, open the software & updates and select the relevant repository and click remove.
2. use the following command in the terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:PPA_Name/ppa
```

ppa - the name of the repository should be same as mentioned in the message your are getting.

Hope this helps

There are some other ways to accomplish the task but these two should be sufficient.